# bind the parameters to an array after passing the array through a function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

**This is my updated code to show what has been done and to help people see easier what im asking for**
in my current project, i am trying to make a page that adds fixture for the top 4 leagues in English football/soccer. with help from others, i have got as far as..

1. created a page with a row of inputs and select-option items that sit inside a form, this row is just one fixture out of a possible 10 or 12 depending which league is selected. with the **one row**, this means i looped through the data and it produces as many rows as that specific league needs.
2. Again, with help from others, the process of preparing, binding and executing the **MySQLi** query seems to be done.

My problem is to do with how to fit it all together. When i validate the form that POSTS the fixtures, do i then call upon a function to *add_fixtures()* to the database. If this is the case, passing the parameters then becomes the issue..

As there will be 10 params coming from each row, then there being upto 12 rows, thats 120 pieces of data to be passed through the function, or is there another way?...
here is the code for my premier_league.php page that is called upon when the premier league is selected in a dropdown menu...

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" class="btn btn-medium btn-success"><br><br>
<?php

$leaguelist = '<option disabled>Please select team</option>';
if ($league_var == NULL) {
    $leaguelist .= '<option "disabled"><strong>Please Select a League Table</strong></h1>';
} else {
    $league_table = get_table($league_var);
    foreach ($league_table as $rows) {    

        $leaguelist .= '<option>'.htmlspecialchars($rows['team']).'</option>';
    }
}
$needed_rows = ceil(count(get_table($league_var)) / 2);
for($i=1; $i <= $needed_rows; $i++){
?>
<select name="result[<?=$i?>][home]" id="" style="width:175px">
<?=$leaguelist?>
</select>

<input type="text" name="result[<?=$i?>][home-score]" class="edit_league_input" value="">
vs
<input type="text" name="result[<?=$i?>][away-score]" class="edit_league_input" name="" value="">
<select name="result[<?=$i?>][away]" id="" style="175px">
<?=$leaguelist?>
</select>
<input type="date" name="result[<?=$i?>][date]" style="width:150px;">
<input type="time" name="result[<?=$i?>][kickoff]" style="width:90px;">
<input type="checkbox" name="result[<?=$i?>][on-tv]" value="Yes" style="margin:-10px 5px 0px 5px;">on T.v
<input type="text" name="result[<?=$i?>][channel]" value="" placeholder="Channel..." style="width:100px;">
<select name="result[<?=$i?>][result]" id="" style="width:125px;">
<option value="">Match Choice...</option>
<option value="HT">Half Time</option>
<option value="FT">Full Time</option>
<option value="P">Postponed</option>
</select>
<br>
<?php
}
```

And then the code mysqli query tha prepares,binds then executes the query is ...

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `fixtures` 
(`home`, `home-score`, `away-score`, `away`, `kickoff`, `on-tv`, `channel`, `league`, `result`, `date`)
 VALUES
 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
foreach($_POST['result'] as $fixture) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $fixture['home']);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $fixture['hs']);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $fixture['as']);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $fixture['away']);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $fixture['kickoff']);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $fixture['on-tv']);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $fixture['channel']);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $fixture['league']);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $fixture['result']);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $fixture['date']);
    $stmt->execute();
```

So i think my question has now changed, i guess its more like ...

**how do i bind the parameters of an array? and how should i pass the array through the function**

i guess thats more fitting to my needs currently.

Comment: WHy are you not creating your 'fixtures' in a loop?

Comment: do you mean like the rows of fixtures? like i have fixture 1 up there.. make that into a loop and depending on the league, how many loops it spits out? something like that?.. and if thats the case, i couldnt think of a way to deal with the name issues for when i send the form.. thats if we are thinking the same thing?

Comment: About so yes. If they're one form anyway, make those names dynamically: `for($i=1; $i <= $needed_rows;$i++){.... <input name="result[<?=$i?>][fieldname]">...}`. Note the use of `[]`'s in those names: if you name a field something like `name[somethingelse]`, it will mean the `$_POST` array has a key `$_POST['name']`, in which there is an array with a key `somethingelse`, with a value in that. [see example #3 here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php), so, you can loop there as well.

Comment: Also, I see you recreating a `<select>` element with `<option value="<?php echo $rows['team'];?>"><?php echo $rows['team'];?></option>` multiple times. While you may want to do something different with the `select` element (names etc.), the options stay the samee: there's nothing wrong with storing that _before_ your loop as a string, and just `echo` that premade HTML out in the select's you are creating.

Comment: so the idea would be for the first row to become the only row, and that first select has the name .. name="h1" ..h being for home or home-team ... where u have result does that need be the same on all the name fields ?... i think i get that the <?=$i?> would basically be the row number and [fieldname] would then be home? so if the result[.. part needs to be the same on them all id change it to <select name="result[<?=$i>][home]" id="">...</select> and so on with the rest, keep the result the same, bu tchange the [fieldname] to what the current name is or an appropriate name anyway?

Comment: and to the $rows['team'] comment... its like that because the function gets what league is selected and pulls the teams from that league and displays them so you can select instead of having to type them out, im not 100% sure what you mean there, do you mean about changing the name="" section of the element ? well the idea would be to keep it like u suggested ?? have it as name="result[<?=$i?>][home]" or away depending which team or even result.. i hope thats what you mean anyway

Comment: Yes, exactly that (think of the names of you'd give those form elements if you would have only one row, and stick `result[<?=$i?>]` in front of it). Which also helps you in the processing, prepare the stament before the loop, and do something like this: `$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);foreach($_POST['result'] as $fixture){ $stmt->bind_param("s", $fixture['home']]);$stmt->bind_param("s", $fixture['away']]);....$stmt->execute();}`. About moving that prepare out of the loop: you want to do as little as possible in loops usually: actions that stay the same throughout you can do before it starts.

Comment: I'll try to summarize it in kind-of-an-answer ;)

Comment: so im just emmending my fixture form, to just one row, and this... for($i=1; $i <= $needed_rows;$i++){..} should this sit inside the form? ok after ive just written it down, here.. it makes more sense that it should, if i put it around the form, that would mean we get a form for each row and thats not good.. so how do i get it to produce the correct number of rows ?

Comment: See my answer below. And you decide what the correct number of rows is... I've added it there as a literal var, but probably, `$needed_rows = ceil(count(get_table($league_var)) / 2);`

Answer (score 1):

To summarize from the comments:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" class="btn btn-medium btn-success"><br><br>
<?php
/*
1. Prepare elements that require actions, but stay the same througout, before the loop:
*/
$leaguelist = '<option disabled>Please select team</option>';
if ($league_var == NULL) {
    $leaguelist .= '<option "disabled"><strong>Please Select a League Table</strong></h1>';
} else {
    $league_table = get_table($league_var);
    foreach ($league_table as $rows) {    
/*
2. Always use htmlspecialchars() if you're outputting something that shouldn't be interpreted as HTNL
2.a If the value is exactly the same as the text in an <option>, you may omit the value=""
*/
        $leaguelist = .'<option>'.htmlspecialchars($rows['team']);'</option>';
    }
}
/*
3. Loop though content that stays the same
*/
$needed_rows = 10;
for($i=1; $i <= $needed_rows; $i++){
?>
<!-- ....................................... FIXTURE 1 .............................................. -->
<!--
4. use names with the [] format, so your POST is a nicely formatted array, and you know wich options belong to each other
-->
<select name="result[<?=$i?>][home]" id="" style="width:175px">
<?=$leaguelist?>
</select>

<input type="text" name="result[<?=$i?>][hs]" class="edit_league_input" value="">
vs
<input type="text" name="result[<?=$i?>][ha]" class="edit_league_input" name="" value="">
<select name="result[<?=$i?>][away]" id="" style="175px">
<?=$leaguelist?>
</select>
....
<?php
}
```

Which makes on the receiving side:

```
//prepare content that stays the same _outside_ of the loop:
$sql = "INSERT INTO `fixtures` 
 (`home`, `home-score`, `away-score`, `away`, `kickoff`, `on-tv`, `channel`, `league`, `result`, `date`)
 VALUES
 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
foreach($_POST['result'] as $fixture) {
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $fixture['home']);
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $fixture['hs']);
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $fixture['as']);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $fixture['away']);
        //...and so on
        $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: so would it make sense for me to do the function/query-prep-bind-execute on that same page? or to have a function on general.func.php ?for some reason $leaguelist='<option>'.htmlspecialchars($rows['team']).'</option>'; is only bringing up West Ham United on its own, you select the box and its the only 1 in there, i feel like im missing something that will be quite obvious lol but what i can see, all looks like should work!..
2.a - i was always told/instructed that value="" should have something in when it can, even when its the same as the actually text, so thats good to actually know! lol ..

Comment: i think my last comment about it only bringing 1 team up, i was thinking it could be to do with my function get_tables($league_var) .. i changed the ASC to DESC and Arsenal came up.. but that doesnt mean its to do with that function, it just mean somewhere, the rest of the teams are not appearing and only the team at the top/bototm of the pile is, but where could that be?

Comment: i have solved the issue of the teams not appearing, the  point of ....
$leaguelist = .'<option>'.htmlspecialchars($rows['team']).'</option>';
the full stop is on the wrong side of the = sign so move to ...
$leaguelist .= '<option>'.htmlspecialchars($rows['team']).'</option>'; and all works fine again

Comment: bet you sick of all these question you wont even know where to start, so as its like 3:32am ill probs stay away and try work on my project till tomorrow night.. but i thought if i ask now and then try work it out if i have issues you maybe able to answer them by time it comes round..all i want to know is with the option that is disabled to start off the list, that doest appear as its disabled...  if i get rid of "disabled" then its selectable but then if that row is submitted it will say "Please pick a team"... my question is, if the row is empty how would i avoid entering it to the database?

Comment: For the empty option: you could give that an empty `value=""` indeed. However: always check server sided whether the row is one you want to insert (validate your inputs). Regarding further questions: try to make them compact & reproducible with a max of 20 rows of code or so, and ask it as a different question here on SO (after you've searched existing answers of course). The question you had here was a bit... wordy, broad & unspecific for the usual SO format ;)

Comment: can i ask, how would i fit that into a function? i dont get how the parameters would pass through, cause in theory, they'll be 10 per row, and up to 12 rows, so what would be the cleanest, most appropriate way to pass the params through the function.. sorry about long delay, ive been trying to sort this out and totally forgot to reply

Comment: so i kept it simple and just POSTED the form and then at the end where a function would go, i ran the sql that you suggested above .. i get Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement for all 10 of the rows of fixtures is this because only trying to bind 10 params when there are really 100 variables ?